# get tags related to entry

Tags: tags

I'm working on Craft plugin which should find entries with special tags.
In my action I have a string:

```
$entries = Entry::find()->section('Projects')->type(['Projects']);
```

and it returns all entries that I should get. But I also need related to this entries tags.

Something like this:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $tags[] = $entry->getRelatedTags();
}
```

But this doesn't work :)

Could anybody help get related to entry tags for entry?

Comment: If I'm following you correctly, are the related tags in a Craft Tag field or are they an Entries field?

Comment: tags are in a Craft Tag Field, as far as I understand

Comment: so. good question is half of answer :) . thanks Brad. this tags was usual fields. and we can handle it as usual fields. for example for tag **location**
`$entry->location->find(`)